# How can a feature have numerical record and still be stored as non numeric?

Tags: python, dataframe, data-science, data-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis

I was working on practicing EDA [FROM THIS LINK](https://miykael.github.io/blog/2022/advanced_eda/) and i saw a line in which there was some type error. i just want to understand how we a dataset have such type of error and how to avoid it ? [image]

Answer (score 0):

You should look [pandas data types](https://pbpython.com/pandas_dtypes.html) closely.

An `object` is a string in pandas so it performs a string operation instead of a mathematical one.